# Accumulator within a DO loop

Tags: fortran, fortran90, accumulator

My goal is to create 10,000 randomly generated numbers between 0 and 1, organize them into ten bins evenly spaced between 0 and 1, and compute a frequency for each bin. This is my code so far.

```
program listrand
implicit none
integer :: n,p
integer :: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = 0
real :: xran
!real, dimension(10,2) :: bin_and_freq -- list of bins and frequency

do n = 1,10000
    call random_number(xran)
            if (xran <  0.1) then
                a = a + 1
            elseif (xran>0.1 .and. xran<0.2) then
                b = b + 1
            elseif (xran>0.2 .and. xran<0.3) then
                c = c+1
            elseif (xran>0.3 .and. xran<0.4) then
                d = d+1
            elseif (xran>0.4 .and. xran<0.5) then
                e = e + 1
            elseif (xran>0.5 .and. xran<0.6) then
                f = f+1
            elseif (xran>0.6 .and. xran<0.7) then
                g = g+1
            elseif (xran>0.7 .and. xran<0.8) then
                h=h+1
            elseif (xran>0.8 .and. xran<0.9) then
                i=i+1
            else
                j = j+1
            endif
enddo
print *, a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j
end program listrand
```

I am getting an unexpected output:
    988        1036   133225987        1004         934         986        1040       33770  1406729616        1052.

Why are c,h, and i so large? Also, is there a more efficient way of going about this than using the unwieldy IF/ELSEIF block I have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your long

```
integer :: a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j = 0
```

You are only initialising `j` to be 0, all others have random numbers in them. If you add

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
d = 0
e = 0
f = 0
g = 0
h = 0
i = 0
j = 0
```

before your loop, everything works well.

As for how to simplify it:

Here is my version of the program:

```
program listrand
implicit none
integer, parameter :: nbins = 10
integer :: n, bin
integer :: bin_hits(nbins)   ! Number of bin hits
real :: xran
real :: bin_lower(nbins)     ! Lower edge of bins
                             ! bin_lower(1) == 0.0

bin_hits = 0

! Set up equidistant bins
bin_lower = [ (real(n-1) / nbins, n = 1, size(bin_lower)) ]

do n = 1,10000
    call random_number(xran)
    bin = count(bin_lower <= xran) 
    bin_hits(bin) = bin_hits(bin)+1
enddo
do n = 1, nbins-1
    print '(2(F6.2), I6)' bin_lower(n), bin_lower(n+1), bin_hits(n)
end do
print '(2(F6.2), I6)' bin_lower(nbins), 1.0, bin_hits(nbins)
end program listrand
```

For the index of which `bin_hits` element to increment, I'm counting the number of values in `bin_lower` that are actually lower than `xran`.

**EDIT**

I'd like to also point to the answer from High Performance Mark a bit further down, who instead of calling `RANDOM_NUMBER` for each value  individually uses it to generate a whole array of random numbers.

Additionally, he's using the fact that the bins are fixed and equidistant to calculate the bin number directly from the random value instead of comparing it to each bin as in my version.

Both of these make the program faster.

Comment: Thanks, the output looks much more reasonable now. In terms of efficiency, is there a better way to approach the problem?

Comment: @yellowblackandrectangular:  What kind of efficiency?  What is your goal by improving "efficiency"?

Comment: I assume that he means: Easier to maintain. Changing the number of bins in his code would be quite a hassle.

Comment: @chw21yeah. I've been looking around and see that maybe an easier way is to make an array where the first column is bins (0-9) and the second column is frequency. Then I could directly reference and increment array elements instead of introducing variables a,b,c,... Anyway, thanks for the help, I'm going to mark this as solved.

Comment: @chw21 Is there a way to print the bins and frequency vertically side-by-side? I ended up making two arrays a and b (each of dimension 10). a is a list of frequencies and b = (/ 0,1,2,3...,9 /). I tried making a new array c that was a combination of a and b but haven't had much luck.

Comment: Ich habe es entsprechend angepasst

Answer (score 4):

If speed of execution is one's main concern, and if one is willing to trade space for time, this might appeal:

```
PROGRAM listrand

  IMPLICIT NONE

  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nbins = 10
  INTEGER, PARAMETER :: nsamples = 10**4
  INTEGER :: bin_hits(0:nbins-1)
  REAL :: xran(nsamples)
  INTEGER :: binned_rn(nsamples), n

  bin_hits = 0

  CALL RANDOM_NUMBER(xran)
  binned_rn = INT(nbins*xran)
  DO n = 1, nsamples
    bin_hits(binned_rn(n)) = bin_hits(binned_rn(n)) +1
  END DO

  WRITE(*,*) bin_hits

END PROGRAM listrand
```

In a limited number of tests this version is 3 - 4 times as fast as @chw21's version.

Comment: Thanks, but when I was talking about efficiency I was more concerned with number of lines of code rather than computation speed. But out of curiosity...how long did each program take to run?

Comment: @yellowblackandrectangular that depends on the compiler and on the machine. Why don't you just compile it yourself and test it. If you are using a Unix/Linux based system, the `time` command tells you exactly how long a program ran for.